# Call Action with props in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm calling an action from a componentDidMount with a property defined on the reducer, but when it reach the action the parameter is not defined.

Here in my component I call the action "fetchAppClasses" with the property (this.props.selection):

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.fetchAppClasses(this.props.selection);    
  }    

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    selection: state.SDWanSelectionReducer
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(sDWanActions, dispatch)
  };
}
```

This is the state that is returned by a reducer:

```
const selection = {
  timespan: "-3660",
  customTimespan: false,
  pathIds: [''],
  source: undefined,
  direction: 0,
  appClassIds: []
};
```

Here in the variable "selection" should be avaivable the parameters passed but is undefined:

```
       export function fetchAppClasses(selection) {
          return function (dispatch) {
            var axcfg = { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': window[config.storageType].token } };
            return axios.get(config.apiUrl + '/sdwan/appClasses', axcfg)
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log('SDWanActions.fetchAppClasses response:', response);
                dispatch(fetchAppClassesSuccess(response.data));
              })      
          }
        }
```

Comment: Did you map `fetchAppClasses` with `mapDispatchToProps`? If not - the action should be invoked using dispatch.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Updating code. Calls the action but not send the params

Comment: If not working you can try with **getState** inside `fetchAppClasses`. Something like: `return function (dispatch,getState) { const {selection} = getState().SDWanSelectionReducer }`

Comment: I have to pass down selection from the function parameter to the axios success. It's reaching the function, but lost on the successs and I need it there.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a race condition that is causing the issue? If the reducer that updates selection is not set before the componentDidMount call then the value may not be set. If you provide your reducer code as well that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return` before the axios call inside your `fetchAppClasses` function.

```
export function fetchAppClasses(selection) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    var axcfg = {
      headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': window[config.storageType].token },
    };

    // remove the return axios.get...
    axios.get(config.apiUrl + '/sdwan/appClasses', axcfg)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(selection); // this should work now...
        console.log('SDWanActions.fetchAppClasses response:', response);
        dispatch(fetchAppClassesSuccess(response.data));
      });
  };
}
```