# Function Parameter undefined on Success with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm calling an action from a componentDidMount with a property defined on the reducer. In the fetchAppClasses action I'm making an get with axios library and in the success I need that property "selection" but is undefined there.

Here in the action:

```
//selection is defined here
       export function fetchAppClasses(selection) {
          return function (dispatch) {
            var axcfg = { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': window[config.storageType].token } };
            return axios.get(config.apiUrl + '/sdwan/appClasses', axcfg)
              .then(function (response) {
//selection in undefined here
                console.log('SDWanActions.fetchAppClasses response:', response);
                dispatch(fetchAppClassesSuccess(response.data));
              })      
          }
        }
```

Comment: change `.then(function (response) {` to `.then(function (response, selection) {`, Anyways i recommend reading more on this.

Comment: Check my answer in your other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958866/call-action-with-props-in-componentdidmount